# What is an effective note taking procedure?

Tags: books, note-taking

I've recently started to use the onenote software to keep track of valuable concepts in different fields of interest. I have constantly found myself dubious during the note taking process. I never know whether I should copy large book paragraphs into my notes or whether I should summarize them. I have little knowledge about how to make the most value out of my note taking process. Is there any good book recommendation or resource to help me answer these kind of questions ?

Comment: The note-taking strategy that will work best for you is the one that works best **for you**, and you are the only person who can figure out waht works best for you.  The most you'll get out of other resources is suggestions for strategies to try.

Comment: you are right, the more I reflect on my note-taking process the more I find myself tuning inefficiencies to match my note taking needs. Although, it would be nice to have some ideas about the note-taking process of highly effective note takers.

Comment: What I do is I read a chunk (maybe a few pages), then I write in my notes something that still represents the material but is *transformative*. I try to write it in a different form or draw relations that weren't mentioned in the text. This avoids just summarizing and replaces it with a process of both thinking about the content and writing it down for future reference.

Comment: @bjb568 - This would make a strong answer, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as IMO it's unanswerable -- that is, it's entirely dependent on the person taking the notes, and the way the question is currently phrased (*Is there any good book recommendation of resource*) is a fishing question. I don't think it's a bad question per se -- I'd love to know the answer myself -- but I don't know if it's a good fit for Academa S.E.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep 2 sub notes per topic, one of them can be composed of excerpts lifted from books/internet, the other can be on your thoughts/summary of the material. 
You can use a standard numbering scheme for both notes to keep track of content; e.g. in notebook 1, 1.2.4 can be Geography>Rivers>Nile in both sub notes.
Take care to paste searchable text and not images of text, for ease of later access.

Answer (score 1):

While large scale educational practice is the subject of a lot of debate, how an individual can best learn things is much more clear.

I'd recommend reading a book like [Your Memory by Kenneth Higbee](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1569246297) to get an understanding of how your memory works and also some basic study/notetaking methods that are justified by evidence. (Over half of the book is on mnemonic techniques, which you might find useful or interesting, but are not required knowledge in my opinion.) There's a lot of flexibility in study methods, but the basic structure of most methods should be the same. For example, the book discusses how the [SQ3R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQ3R) study method is basically the same as many others. You should use the basic structure of a good study method to help you design a method that works for you.

Notably absent from the book is [spaced repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition) software like [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/). I use this when I'd benefit from having information of interest memorized (e.g., for engineering work this tends to be definitions, shortcuts, and common misconceptions). I don't use it for information I expect to use infrequently. [Gwern](https://www.gwern.net/Spaced%20repetition#how-much-to-add) has some additional thoughts about when to use this sort of software.

In my personal case, I tend to have multiple tiers of notes. At the lowest level are handwritten notes, which tend to be scanned and then discarded to save space. Above that are text files, usually in an outline format. I find text files are easiest for combining excerpts and my own thoughts, and also for keeping track of questions/hypotheses I have. The outline structure is very easy to reorganize as well. The excerpts are obviously quoted, and my thoughts are not. Above that are more carefully typed notes, whether in TeX, HTML, or something else. If I want to excerpt something there, I'll use blockquotes or inline quotes. Parallel to these options are my Anki cards, which often duplicate things in other notes. Which option I might use for a particular subject I'm learning depends on the subject and how much time and effort I'm able to put in.